# Could someone explain the ORM used in current web frameworks?

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, orm, fuelphp

I'm very new to ORM and I kind of understand the definition. Confusion starts when I try to implement relations.

Suppose I have these two tables.

**Products table:**

```
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| brand_id    | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| name        | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description | text         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

**Brand names table:**

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name       | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

How do I set up the models with `$_has_many` `$_belongs_to` so that when I do `$product1 = Model_Product::find('first');`
It also returns the name of the brand, like in SQL joins.

Or am I going about this the wrong way.

**This doesn't have to be specific to fuelphp, I just want how to setup ORMs in this case.**

Comment: I think your first problem is that you're assuming that ORM implementations are all the same, the concept should be similar, but implementations depend on the opinions of the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fuelphp you can use ORM simpli define the relation in the model file:

**model/brand.php**

```
class Model_Brand extends Orm\Model {

   protected static $_has_many = array(
        'products' => array(
            'model_to' => 'Model_Product',
            'key_from' => 'id',
            'key_to' => 'brand_id',
            'cascade_save' => false,
            'cascade_delete' => true,
        )
    );
}
```

**model/product.php**

```
class Model_Product extends Orm\Model {
    protected static $_belongs_to = array('brand');
}
```

When you'll perform `$brand = Model_Brand::find('first');` you can access list of products with `$brand['products']`

When you'll perform `$product = Model_Product::find('first');` you can access the brand with `$product['brand']`

Answer (score 1):

An example in a somewhat Rails-ish way would be:

```
class Brand
  has_many :products
end

class Product
  belongs_to :brand
end

product = Product.first
product.brand
=> <#Brand...>
brand = Brand.first
brand.products
=> [<#Product...>, <#Product...>]
```

This isn't complete code by any means but hopefully you'll get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was actually hoping for an explanation in regards to actual joins in SQL.

Comment: Are you looking for an example of how to do a join query that includes data from both tables?

Comment: that I know. I'm confused as to how it relates to ORMs.

Comment: your request is outrageously broad, have you considered just looking at the source of an ORM?